# Why only up to two \[Prime] superscripts are interpreted as derivatives?

Tags: syntax, boxes, expression-construction

I noticed that only up to two `\[Prime]` superscripts are interpreted as derivatives. Is there a reason for this restriction? Is it documented?

```
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["Sin","\[Prime]"][x]\)
(* Cos[x] *)

\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["Sin","\[Prime]\[Prime]"][x]\)
(* -Sin[x] *)

\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["Sin","\[Prime]\[Prime]\[Prime]"][x]\)
(* (Sin^\[Prime]\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] *)
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

---

The regular apostrophe can be used any number of times though:

```
Sin'''[x]
(* -Cos[x] *)
```

Comment: It is sort-of Documented in that only Prime and DoublePrime are defined..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is not a restriction, but this comes with the way how *Mathematica* formats derivatives. That being said, the same way you cannot use 3 superscript primes to input a third derivative, you won't see 3 primes in the output either.

```
D[f[x], x, x, x]
```

gives

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you *could* type this as input, then you would have a way to specify your third derivative with a superscript. Unfortunately, there is a hidden `TagBox` in the above superscript which cannot be entered easily.

To answer your question: You can use superboxed primes as input for derivative, because *Mathematica* interprets your box expression correctly. Since 3 primes never occur to represent the third derivative, you cannot use it as valid input.